# getting every count of distinct ids per day

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by, timestamp, distinct

I have a table that records online activity on a website

```
ID | Day         | Action 
---|-------------|-------
1  | 2016-01-01  | Log in
---|-------------|-------
2  | 2016-01-01  | Log in
---|-------------|-------
1  | 2016-01-01  | Log off
---|-------------|-------
2  | 2016-01-01  | Ask Question
---|-------------|-------
3  | 2016-01-01  | Log in
---|-------------|-------
2  | 2016-01-02  | Log in
---|-------------|-------
1  | 2016-01-02  | Log in
---|-------------|-------
1  | 2016-01-02  | Ask Question
---|-------------|-------
```

I want to count the amount of users who used the website on day x
like this:

```
|Day         |Count|
|------------|-----|
|2016-01-01  |  3  |
|------------|-----|
|2016-01-02  |  2  |
```

If I do a normal counting query like

```
SELECT day, COUNT(distinct id) FROM data GROUP BY 1
```

it will only count the entry where the user used the site for the very first time.

How do I do this counting query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the table as you have outlined and executed the following query:

```
select day, count(distinct id1) from test group by day
```

and I got the following:

```
24-OCT-16   3
28-OCT-16   2
```

The only thing I changed was group by 1 to group by day as I am using Oracle. Are you looking for some different result?

Comment: huh, when i first did the code i got "worng" numbers (like mentions before) but now some how it works (with both group by versions) well it works thank you very much